# I need to close all windows using the app.quit() but it won't work because some windows are hidden

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a simple app that has just two windows that never show up at the same time but are always working, just one of them hidden. I've been trying to use the `app.quit()` method to close them but it won't work, the window I close stops running but the process in the terminal will continue since the other window is running. How can I solve the problem?

Here's the code

```
const app = electron.app
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
var path = require('path')

const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

//when app ready it will create the window
app.on('ready', function () {
    //create the first window
    let loginWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        [...]
        
    webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    loginWindow.once('ready-to-show', function () {
        loginWindow.show()   
    })

    //create the forgotten password window
    let forgotPasswordWindow = new BrowserWindow({
       [...]
        
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })
    
    forgotPasswordWindow.once('ready-to-show', function () {
        forgotPasswordWindow.hide()
    })

    ipcMain.on('forgotpassword-from-login', function () {
        forgotPasswordWindow.show(loginWindow.hide())
    })
    
    ipcMain.on('login-from-forgotpassword', function () {
        forgotPasswordWindow.hide(loginWindow.show())
    })

});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (forgotPasswordWindow.closed === true && loginWindow.show === false) {
        app.quit()
    }
    else if (loginWindow.closed === true && forgotPasswordWindow.show === false) {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

The piece of code at the end was just an attempt I made, consider I'm a total beginner. 
Thank you already for any answer!

Comment: To close the window, you want to call the close() function on it just like you did with `loginWindow.show()` you can call `loginWindow.close()` By default if all windows are closed the app will terminate

Comment: You can consider using `app.exit()`. It will absolutely close all the windows (ungracefully).

Comment: The event `window-all-closed` is only emitted when all the windows have been closed so right now your code there will not be hit. Also you do not need to call app.quit() inside window-all-closed since by default it quits the app.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to [Halmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9877620/halmon)'s answer I got to the easy solution, I set the close button on both windows to close both of them when pressed, so now `app.quit()` will work just fine.

The code now looks just like before, I've just added an `ipcMain` function to close the windows that looks like this:

```
ipcMain.on('close-all-windows', function() {
    forgotPasswordWindow.close(loginWindow.close())
})
```

And at the end, the last `app.on` function looks like this:

```
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

Thanks to everyone for the help